# Can I draw outline as the image in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Can I draw outline as the image?

If there is a white background image without outline, can I draw outline along the image by using CoreGraphics or code?

Comment: Are you talking about edge detection here?

Comment: It means outline of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through every pixel in the image and set them to black if they fulfil the conditions. Or `Edge Detection` is another way to do it.

You can also refer this thread:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

Comment: could you explain, how the linked thread is related to this question? I dont get it…

Answer (score 1):

Simple border around your UIImageView

Include the QuartzCore framework first.
Click on your project -> Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries -> Add QuartzCore.framework

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

```
self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
// You can also add a shadow
self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);

// If you do this in the controller and not the view it would of course be
// myImageView.layer instead of self.layer
```